# What wrong with .onclick() event?

Tags: javascript, api, if-statement, content-management-system, velo

im newbie on javascript

I try add .onclick() action on wix console interface but i think i made some error on my code :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2P7b.jpg)

```
import {local} from 'wix-storage';
import wixWindow from 'wix-window';

 $w.onReady(function () {
   if('#button2').onClick {
     wixWindow.openLightbox("Conditions générales de vente");
 }
} );
```

I try to understanding the particularly `.onClick()` on their API but i do not see...

https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/$w/selectiontags/onclick

Thanks

Comment: That's not valid JavaScript syntax.

Comment: Why do you have it in an `if` statement?

Comment: Your code doesn't look like any of the examples on the page you linked to.

Comment: @Barmar I need `if` statement because once the user clicks on submit a lightbox (modal) should open

Comment: You don't need `if` for that. That's what `onClick` does, it registers a function to run when the user clicks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onClick()` is a function. The event handler is the argument to the function.

```
$w.onReady(() => {
  $w('#button2').onClick(() => {
    wixWindow.openLightbox("Conditions générales de vente");
  });
});
```